# Ideal Reversible Heat Engine Entropy

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, reversibility, heat-engine

For an ideal reversible heat engine, what is the entropy change of the system (heat engine) after 100 cycles? What contribution does the heat engine make to the entropy change of the universe?

Answer (score 3):

The entropy change of a system that undergoes a complete cycle, meaning the system begins and returns to the same equilibrium state, is always zero, whether the cycle is reversible or not. If its true for one cycle, its true for 100 cycles. That is because entropy is a property of the system. The difference in entropy between two equilibrium states of a system is the same regardless of the path (process) connecting the two states.

The same cannot be said for the surroundings. The entropy change for the surrounding after a complete system cycle is zero only if the cycle is reversible. For an irreversible cycle the entropy of the surrounding is positive.

So the heat engine in an irreversible cycle increases the entropy of the surroundings. That means the total entropy of the universe increases for an irreversible cycle.

Hope this helps.